# Alamofire JSON .GET encoding to array

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm getting web contents from web service. I have array like this

```
"dc:creator": [ "Emre Degirmenci"]
```

I want to show in label.text with Alamofire. I am getting this error

```
"Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails".
```

I used [String:Any]but did not success.

This is my NSObject object

```
var webCreaterName: [String:Any] = [:]
```

This is my WebService code

```
func getWebContentsCompleted(){

    var contents: [WebContents] = []
    let headers = [
        "Authorization": "\(self.defaults.object(forKey: "AccessToken")!)",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(APIURL.GetWebContents.rawValue, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
       // debugPrint("response: \(response)")

        let httpCode = response.response!.statusCode

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
          let json = JSON(value)

        switch httpCode {
        case 200:

if let webContentDcCretorName = data[i]["dc:creator"] as? [String:Any] {
                    content.webCreaterName = webContentDcCretorName
                }
```

Comment: how even you declare / assign `data`

Comment: let data = json["data"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for key `dc:creator` is an array so you have to declare

```
var webCreaterName = [String]()
```

Obviously you are using SwiftyJSON. To get a Swift array from `JSON` type use `arrayObject`

```
if let webContentDcCretorName = data[i]["dc:creator"].arrayObject as? [String] {
   content.webCreaterName = webContentDcCretorName
}
```